# Check whether Everyone group is allowed in file ACL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, acl, file-access

I would like to check if **Everyone** user group is strictly mentioned in file ACL and if any user from this group can access this file e.g. for write operations.

To achieve this I'm looking for **Everyone** group SID:

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
dwRes = AllocateAndInitializeSid(
    &SIDAuthWorld, 
    1,
    SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pSIDEveryone);
```

I also get copy of file Security Descriptor and ACL:

```
dwRes = GetNamedSecurityInfo(
    lpszOwnFile,                 
    SE_FILE_OBJECT,             
    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
    NULL, 
    NULL,                      
    &pACL,                        
    NULL,
    &pSecDesc);
```

Now I got two options:

1. I can manually get every ACE from ACL and validate it's access mask against **Everyone** group.
2. I can use **AccessCheck** method to check if impersonated token can access file for given operations.

I would like to avoid implementing 1. option because it will require a lot of checks (different kind of ACE, matching access masks, and so on)
I would like to simply call **AccessCheck** method, but this method requires handle to impersonation token as input parameter. The problem is that (as I found in web) I can't create impersonated token basing only on group SID, I need also user SID.

I imagine corner case when Everyone group has access to file but this particular user (from impersonated token) has no access. In this situation **AccessCheck** will return wrong verdict.

My questions;

1. Is there any option to create impersonation token basing only on group SID?
2. Can I use some kind of default user SID that I can use for impersonation token which will not distort the result?
3. Is there other way to check if particular group has some kind of access to given file?
4. Is the manual ACEs check the only option to do this?

Comment: if we have *SeTcbPrivilege* (or with *SeDebugPrivilege* we can get tcb) we can create any token from scratch. with only `Everyone` sid too. also possible create restricted token with `Everyone` in restricted sids, but anyway - windows not "allow" some sid in object dacl. it allow access via concrete token, with all it sids, integrity level, etc. if you want *exactly* result - you need *exactly* token. and what sense in this check at all ? for what this ? manual ACEs not hard. of course this will be not exactly, but without concrete token you not got better result

Comment: You could use [`GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446637) for this check. Note that the actual access granted to a token that has the everyone SID enabled in its groups may be less, depending on deny ACEs, the SACL's mandatory label (integrity level and read-up, write-up, and execute-up policy), and the token's restricting SIDs, mandatory policy (default no write-up), and integrity level.

Comment: A token's access could also be *more* based solely on this everyone SID, depending on object policy. For example, read-attributes and delete access are granted to a file if the token is respectively granted read and delete-child access to the containing directory. This can't be determined from a single `AccessCheck`. You have to check the parent separately.

Comment: @RbMm The usage is that another application creates file with "Everyone" full-control access. My service (which runs as a Local Service) must write something to this file. If someone delete this file and create hardlink to another file, My service will override this file. I thought that checking if "Everyone" group can still access this file is a good option (if "Everyone" can't access this file it means that hardlink was probably created and my service should not write to this file).

Comment: @Klepak - no, this is not good option for this. nothing prove.

Comment: and at all - why you not check for some *exactly* SD in this case ?

Comment: also say how about mandatory label in sd ? which integrity level assume for everyone ? this of course related to original question

Comment: If you're in control of this other application and running on Windows Vista or later, you could maybe configure your service as `SERVICE_SID_TYPE_UNRESTRICTED` to get an "NT SERVICE\\[service name]" SID in your token. Then the other application can grant access to the file for this service SID specifically. If your service SID isn't present, then it's not your file. Otherwise you could save the file ID and subsequently open by ID.